# Dividing column values based on other column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to measure the growth over time of some sales data. I've grouped current and previous sales together based on the last n months, yielding the following (abbreviated) table:

```
+-------------------------------+---------------+-------------+
| CUSTOMER_NAME                 | TIMEFRAME     | GROSS_SALES |
+-------------------------------+---------------+-------------+
| SALLY'S SALES INC             | CURRENT       |     1207.76 |
| SALLY'S SALES INC             | PREVIOUS      |     8139.49 |
| DAVES PRODUCTS LLC            | CURRENT       |      909.92 |
| DAVES PRODUCTS LLC            | PREVIOUS      |     2867.41 |
| MEGACORP                      | CURRENT       |     8369.05 |
| MEGACORP                      | PREVIOUS      |    19123.75 |
+-------------------------------+---------------+-------------+
```

I'm trying to calculate the quotient between the current and previous sales, something like

```
+-------------------------------+----------------+
| CUSTOMER_NAME                 | SALES_FACTOR   |
+-------------------------------+----------------+
| SALLY'S SALES INC             | 0.148382761082 |
| DAVES PRODUCTS LLC            | 0.317331668649 |
| MEGACORP                      | 0.690302092999 |
+-------------------------------+----------------+
```

But, I can't figure out a query which correctly divides the two values for each customer name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` to get one row per customer, then `SUM(CASE)` to pick out the current and previous values.

This has the advantage of only scanning the table once, rather than needing a join.

```
SELECT
   CUSTOMER_NAME,
   SUM(CASE WHEN TIMEFRAME = 'CURRENT'  THEN GROSS_SALES END)
   /
   SUM(CASE WHEN TIMEFRAME = 'PREVIOUS' THEN GROSS_SALES END)  AS SALES_FACTOR
FROM
   yourTable
GROUP BY
   CUSTOMER_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the table twice with different names...

```
select CUSTOMER_NAME, t1.TIMEFRAME/t2.TIMEFRAME 
  from TABLE_NAME as t1, TABLE_NAME as t2 
 where t1.CUSTOMER_NAME = t2.CUSTOMER_NAME 
   and t1.TIMEFRAME  = 'PREVIOUS' 
   and t2.TIMEFRAME = 'CURRENT'
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses conditional aggregation:

```
select customer_name,
       (max(case when time_frame = 'Current' then gross_sales end) /
        max(case when time_frame = 'Previous' then gross_sales end)
       ) as ratio
from t
group by customer_name;
```

Comment: ++ ..! May you please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897213/how-can-i-break-selecting-when-condition-is-false) ?