# How can I break selecting when condition is false?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
// QandA
+----+-----------+-----------------------+-----------+------+---------+
| id |   title   |        content        |  related  | type | deleted |
+----+-----------+-----------------------+-----------+------+---------+
| 1  | question1 | content of question1  | 1         | 0    | 0       |
| 2  | answer1-1 | content of answer1-1  | 1         | 1    | 0       |
| 3  | question2 | content of question2  | 3         | 0    | 0       |
| 4  | answer1-2 | content of answer1-2  | 1         | 1    | 0       |
| 5  | answer2-1 | content of answer2-1  | 3         | 1    | 0       |
+----+-----------+-----------------------+-----------+------+---------+
```

- **`related`** column is containing the id of question for itself all its own answers.
- **`type`** column is `0` for questions and `1` for answers.
- **`deleted`** column is `0` when question\answer isn't deleted and `1` when it is deleted.

Also Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM QandA WHERE related = :id AND deleted = 0
```

---

**My question:** How can I implement this condition:

If `deleted` is `1` THEN:

1. if `type` is `0` *(it is a question)* then select nothing
2. if `type` is `1` *(it is a answer)* then only don't select that row

Comment: can you better explain `if type is 1 (it is a answer) then only don't select that row`?

Comment: @vkp I want when a question is removed, then nothing select. But if a answers is removed, just that answer doesn't select.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to exclude all the answers of deleted questions:

1) Deleted should be 0

2) It should be a question or (if it is an answer) it shouldn't belong to a deleted question

```
SELECT * FROM QandA qa
WHERE 
    related = :id
    AND deleted = 0
    AND (
        type = 0
        OR NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT * FROM QandA q WHERE q.id = qa.related AND q.deleted
        )
    )
```

Comment: Where is `WHERE related = :id` ?